# How to get Stack to rewrite my Setup.hs file, after changing to Custom build type?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

My project has local external dependencies.
So, I've changed the *build-type* field, in my *.cabal file, to "Custom" and added these sections to my *stack.yaml* file:

```
- location: ../loc_deps
  subdirs:
  - loc_dep1
  - loc_dep2
  extra-dep: true

explicit-setup-deps:
  "*": true # change the default
```

But, I can't figure out how to get Stack to rewrite my *Setup.hs* file, to track these local external dependencies.

In response to the first comment, below:

1. Is this a sufficient *Setup.hs* for a Custom build-type?:

   import Distribution.Simple
   main = defaultMain
2. I'm expecting that if I touch *../loc_deps/loc_dep1/NeededModule.hs* and then run a "stack build", I'll see *NeededModule.hs* get recompiled, but I'm not seeing that.

In response to @mgsloan (first comment below):
Wrt/ this:
*Dependencies do not go in your custom Setup.hs*
So, then, is this verbiage, taken from the [*stack.yaml* fields descriptions page](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#explicit-setup-deps), out of date?:

> Decide whether a custom Setup.hs script should be run with an explicit
>   list of dependencies, based on the dependencies of the package itself.
>   It associates the name of a local package with a boolean. When it's
>   true, the Setup.hs script is built with an explicit list of packages.

Comment: > But, I can't figure out how to get Stack to rewrite my Setup.hs file, to track these local external dependencies.

Hmm, not sure what you mean by this.  When using custom Setup.hs, the cabal file is still consulted.  Dependencies do not go in your custom Setup.hs, but in the "build-depends" section in cabal.  Stack does not automatically update / rewrite either cabal or Setup.hs files (well, there is an exception there with "stack upload --pvp-bounds", but that can be ignored).

Comment: Thanks! So, two questions:

1. Is this a sufficient Setup.hs for a Custom build-type?:

    import Distribution.Simple
    main = defaultMain

2. If I touch ../loc_deps/loc_dep1/NeededModule.hs and then "stack build", should I expect to see ../loc_deps/loc_dep1/NeededModule.hs get recompiled? Currently, I'm not, which is what prompted me to write this question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that formatting doesn't work in comments. Please, see edited original question. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @mgsloan, just wondering if you'd had a chance to look at my most recent edits to the original question, and if you had any comments. Thanks!

Comment: That should work, but note that it will have the same behavior as simple build type.  Does NeededModule get recompiled in that case?  I'm guessing it's not in your list of `exposed-modules` / `other-modules`.  If it is indeed a dependency of one of the modules in the package, then stack will warn that it is an unlisted module.